# Update table values from another table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a temporary table havinf 2 colums and i need to update this data into another table

[image]

Can Some one please help me with this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No images please. Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `join`, something like this:

```
update othertable t join
       temporarytable tt
       on t.clientid = tt.clientid
    set t.checklist = tt.checklist;
```